# Pythons Pandas, applying function on a GroupBy Object "indexes"

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am sure there is a better solution to my current problem in Pandas :

I have a Dataframe with columns like

```
df.columns = ['bar','foo',0,1,2]
```

I want to call a SQL database, where I filter with the tuple of bar and foo values, calculate something with the returned result using columns 0 and 1, and return the result to column 3.

For the moment I do this with a groupby, and didn't find anywhere the proper way to use the transform method after this.

```
groups = df.groupby('bar','foo')
for (bar,foo), group in groups:
  db_results = read_db(bar,foo)
  df[3].loc(groups.groups((bar,foo))) = f(db_results,df[0].loc(...),df[1].loc(...))
```

I believe this is a little bit ugly, right ? There must be something more with less redudency than the df.loc everywhere. But I don't how to access bar, foo using tranform method of Groupby objects.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with custom function:

```
def func(x):
     db_results = read_db(x.name[0],x.name[1])
     x[3] = f(db_results, x[0], x[1])
     return x

df = df.groupby(['bar','foo']).apply(func)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:list('abcdef'),
                   'foo':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   1:[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   2:[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'bar':list('aaabbb')}, columns=['bar','foo',0,1,2])
print (df)
  bar  foo  0  1  2
0   a    4  a  7  1
1   a    5  b  8  3
2   a    4  c  9  5
3   b    5  d  4  7
4   b    5  e  2  1
5   b    4  f  3  0

def func(x):
    print (x.name[0])
    x[3] = (x[2] + x[1]) * x.name[1]
    return x

df = df.groupby(['bar','foo']).apply(func)
print (df)
  bar  foo  0  1  2   3
0   a    4  a  7  1  32
1   a    5  b  8  3  55
2   a    4  c  9  5  56
3   b    5  d  4  7  55
4   b    5  e  2  1  15
5   b    4  f  3  0  12
```